# Calculate correlation on categorical data

Tags: correlation

I have categorical data where values are string. Gender, City and Country are my input data. My output class is also string values. The below table explains the data:

Gender      City      Country      Output

M           XYZ       A            Converted

F           KLM       Z            Converted

M           KLM       M            Not Converted

F           ABC       M            Converted

First question, can I calculate correlation between input columns and output? If yes, how and by which method? I am using Python, any suggestion on library function would be great.